# Passing Variable from Form to Class C#

Tags: c#, forms, class, parameter-passing

I'm working on a simple form that has multiple TabPages with a single listbox in each of them.  When the use clicks OK, I search through which TabPage is active, and which SelectedItem is current and set to a variable.  No problems there.

My class "cmdObjStyles.cs" calls the form "frmObjStyles.cs, gets the results from the user, and pulls the results back into the class cmdObjStyles.cs.

Problem is that variables "curTab and "curItem" (which are the strings I want to bring back to my class become out of context when the Form closes.

So I tried setting the variables to public, but after reading through a bunch of posts, this isn't good practice.  I then tried to use Get,Set but I couldn't get that to work, and I don't really understand it from the videos online about them.

There must be an easier way to do this..

My From OK code:

```
        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
        // Get the currently selected item from the Active Tab and ListBox
        string curTab = tabCntrlObjStyle.SelectedTab.Text;
        string voidCurItem = "-----------------------";
        if (curTab == "General")
        {
            string curItem = lstBoxGen.GetItemText(lstBoxGen.SelectedItem);
            if (curItem.Equals(voidCurItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Valid Revit Category", "Re-Select Item from List: ");
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Close();
            }
        }
        if (curTab == "Structural")
        {
            string curItem = lstBoxStruc.GetItemText(lstBoxStruc.SelectedItem);
            if (curItem.Equals(voidCurItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Valid Revit Category", "Re-Select Item from List: ");
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Revit Category in Invalid", "Invalid Selection: ");
        }


    }
```

And my simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace STN_BIM_Manager_Ribbon
{
[Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class cmdObjStyles : IExternalCommand
{
    static AddInId appId = new AddInId(new Guid("2E66FC45-F0AC-4212-9BCE-E8C331A8CC66"));
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;
        string curItem;
        string curItem2;

        // Start User Form and Get Input
        using (frmObjStyles thisForm = new frmObjStyles())
        {
            thisForm.ShowDialog();
            if (thisForm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }

            curItem2 = thisForm.tabCntrlObjStyle.SelectedTab.ToString();
            curItem = thisForm.lstBoxStruc.SelectedItem.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("This is your Selected Value: " + 
                Environment.NewLine + curItem + 
                Environment.NewLine + curItem2,
                "Your Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            // Create a Collection of Values a user can Select
            //List<string> structList = new List<string>(structInput);



        }

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said create public properties in your form that will get set when the user clicks the OK button,also set the form AcceptButton property to btnOk.Now in your cmdObjStyles class in your Execute method try this(inside the using statement):

```
using (frmObjStyles thisForm = new frmObjStyles())
{
     thisForm.ShowDialog();
     if (thisForm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
          //curItem2 = thisForm.tabCntrlObjStyle.SelectedTab.ToString();
          curItem2 = thisForm.ThePropertyYouCreated;
          //curItem = thisForm.lstBoxStruc.SelectedItem.ToString();
          curItem = thisForm.TheOtherPropertyYouCreated;
          MessageBox.Show("This is your Selected Value: " +
          Environment.NewLine + curItem +
                        Environment.NewLine + curItem2,
                        "Your Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
          // Create a Collection of Values a user can Select
          //List<string> structList = new List<string>(structInput);
          //it would probably be better to place this next here...
          //return Result.Succeeded;
     }
     else
     {
          return Result.Cancelled;
     }


}
```